# jQuery - How to get maximum characters can fit for given width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert long string to array because I want to use this plugin: http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/. I made a simple function for this purpose but when I tried to get maximum characters it showed different value than actual result. Here is my code :

```
$paHeader = $('.pa-header');

let $b       = $paHeader.find('b').text();
let bLength  = $b.length; //295 characters
let bTLength = bLength * 14; // 295 * 14px (fontsize) = 4130px

let container     = Math.floor($(window).width() - 14); //1889 - 14 = 1875 just for safety
let maxFontPerRow = Math.floor(container / 14); //134 characters
```

Where the actual number of characters can be displayed roughly 261 instead of 134. Below is the information of my browser:

```
http://whatsmy.browsersize.com/

Browser window width: 1920
Browser window height:  950
Screen width: 1920
Screen height:  1080
Screen color depth: 24
```

CSS

```
.pa-header {
  background-color: #F58334;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 44px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

How to do this correctly? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does CSS affect the rendering of the `document`?

Comment: Yes, I use CSS for some styling. I will update my code.

Answer (score 0):

If CSS does not affect the rendering of the `document` you can use `window.innerWidth` to get the width of the viewport, or `Element.getBoundingClientRect().width` to get the width of an element, for example `document.body`.

Comment: `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width` return 1903 while `window.innerWidth` return 1920. The latter one return 136 for `maxFontPerRow`

Comment: Is that expected result?

Comment: Yes, the width is expected. But when I calculate how many characters can fit for that width it return unexpected result. When I try with responsive,  `maxFontPerRow` return 67 while the maximum text displayed is 120 (Almost twice).

Comment: Would suggest to review several posts and articles on CSS units and `font-size`. You can use `calc()` to set `font-size` to a divisor of either `.getBoundClientRect().width` or `window.innerWidth`

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestion, I will search more about `font-size` and `calc()`